# "high sierra" pdo_mysql?

Tags: macos, pdo

I upgrade my sierra to High sierra, then found my php database connection does not work anymore. It turns out the PDO_MYSQL driver is not installed by default. I reinstalled the mysql, which does not help.

Does anyone else have the same problem? How can I install the PDO driver?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue upgrading today. I was using brewed versions of php. Moved to 'native' setup now. Mysql 5.7 was installed and working pre the update. The connection still works when you put in 127.0.0.1 as a host name.

Lands up that the php.ini file is not created on update, meaning that the location of the mysql socket is incorrect.

To fix this, I copied the /etc/php.default to /etc/php.ini

Once done, open terminal and run

```
mysql_config --socket
```

Keep the output.

Open the php.ini file and find/edit this line.

```
mysqli.default_socket =/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Save and restart the apache server

```
sudo apachectl restart
```